# Creating magnetic material

Tags: magnetic-fields, material-science

I’m trying to figure out the best way to magnetize a plastic used for a child’s toy. The idea is each piece would not repel eachother but either attract or do nothing when brought close together. When a larger but lightweight magnet is brought near, the toy would stick to the magnet. Some of the toys are extremely small so I’m thinking more of a magnetic dust that can be added to a plastic without losing its magnetic properties. The other criteria would be non-toxic obviously as children would be using it and lastly low cost. Feel free to respond with any comments, suggestions or ideas that may help me design this product.

Comment: iron filings might do the trick. easily available and not toxic. You need to ingest about [30 grams/kg bodyweight to die](http://www.sciencelab.com/msds.php?msdsId=9924400) (if you're a rat).

Comment: Ferrite-filled rubber in magnetic sheet that attaches to the fridge